# How to reference another project in a .properties file

Tags: java, spring, properties, spring-boot

I want to set a property in a `.properties` file. It should reference another package or project. I am using spring / spring boot

For example:

`some_file: ${another_package_name}/src/main/resources/some_file.txt`

Comment: Can you provide more details about the context ? Pure Java ? Spring ? What do you want to achieve : include properties from another file ?

Comment: The property (some_file) expects a file path. But instead of referencing a file in this package, I want to reference one in different package.

Comment: I hope you also appreciate the (for you marginal) boost in reputation and the hereby correction of answer-hierarchy within this question. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where you say ${another_package_name} that is where the project would be for a gradle or maven project so I'm going to assume you are attempting to cross reference resources between projects.

The location of

```
${another_package_name}/src/main/resources/some_file.txt
```

could also be called

```
classpath:some_file.txt
```

So then you would just need to make sure that both projects are on the classpath and then some_file.txt should be available to the project as a whole.

Reference

> http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is not possible.

Java properties do not have any semantic values; they are just dumb strings with key / value. If you want such logic, you have to build yourself; like some "processor" that checks for the presence of certain properties and that then "interprets" the value as file name of another property file.

You might want to check if there are any libraries out there that provide such logic.

Comment: I forgot to mention: I am using spring / spring boot (see edit)